# highslide gallery wide first image shows behind smaller subsequent images

Tags: highslide

I'm populating a gallery (without controls) from a set of random images selected from a MySQL table.  If the first image loaded is wider than the others in the selected set, its edges show during all slide transitions.  If the first image is one of the smaller ones, ALL images (including the wider image) transition properly.

Setting the background to none and removing outlines does not solve the problem.

Is there a way to avoid seeing edges of the first image if it is the widest in the gallery?

The effect can be seen at http://www.tbkd.org/MEX-Dev_2/indexz.php

Comment: What should I click to see that effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding `class="hidden-container"` to the div inside your `gallery-area` div.The hidden-container class is predefined in your highslide.css file.

Change this:

```
<div id="gallery-area" style="position:absolute; top:68px; left:245px; width: 240px; height: 180px; margin: 2px 2px 0px 10px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="gallery-area" style="position:absolute; top:68px; left:245px; width: 240px; height: 180px; margin: 2px 2px 0px 10px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="hidden-container">
```